# Rice paper cake toppers

Tags: cake, icing

How long will they stay looking good after placing on the cake, I'm using one on an iced rich fruit cake & trying to finish it a couple of weeks before the party

Answer (score 3):

I saw no degradation in image quality (custom printed ones) in a few days. If the icing is hard then you moisten it just enough for the rice paper to stick before letting it dry again you *should* be fine as there's no source of moisture to make the ink suffer. But of course check the instructions - I think mine used alcohol-based inks.

But why not ice the cake in advance then add the topper the day before serving?

Comment: Yup that is what I would do, just add the topper on the day of serving, then you will not have to worry about colors leeching.